# Adding dependencies with '@' in version for brownie project

Tags: brownie

I am trying to add superfluid-finance/protocol-monorepo@ethereum_contracts@v1.3.0 into my brownie project.

brownie-config.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  - superfluid-finance/protocol-monorepo@ethereum_contracts@v1.3.0

compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@superfluid-finance=superfluid-finance/protocol-monorepo@ethereum_contracts@v1.3.0'
```

However, since the version has '@' in it, I am getting:

```
ValueError: Invalid package ID. Must be given as [ORG]/[REPO]@[VERSION]
```

How can I add a dependency where the version has '@' in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in implementation of brownie, when extracting dependencies package ID, it just simply split with `@` character to get the version like this:

```
path, version = package_id.split("@")
```

so if the version part of a dependency path includes `@`, it makes an error, and brownie can not get it from Github.

In the normal case, you can simply solve this problem by using other versions of repo that `ethereum-contracts` the same. But with `superfluid-finance/protocol-monorepo` repo it is impossible beacause all of its version after `ethereum_contracts@v1.3.0` still contain `@`.

If you still want to use this dependency, you can make a clone of it and set release version simply to `1.0.0`. Brownie can also import dependencies with **ethPM** but I do not have experience with this, you can learn more about it [here](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/package-manager.html#installing-from-ethpm) if you want.